# Do I need to change nginx configuration to set up a subdomain for my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I am having a problem testing a subdomain for my app. I read in a post that `lvh.me` will translate into `localhost`. This has worked well for me in my development environment. I've modified my rails app's `routes.rb` to have this code:

```
constraints(Codeopenhub) do
  get '/', to: 'codeopenhub#index'
  get '/*other', to: 'codeopenhub#index'
end
```

Basically the code is saying that if you hit `code.openhub.net/anything`, you'll hit a particular page. Now when I deploy this onto my staging environment, this doesn't work at all. Hitting the subdomain says that the site can't be reached. `server DNS address could not be found.` Do I need to add an accompanying modification to `nginx/sites-enabled or nginx/sites-available`? Or perhaps I need an entry in `/etc/hosts`?

I was following these resources but now I'm a bit stuck and hit a wall. Could someone lend me a hand? It would be greatly appreciated.

[Dealing with Subdomains](https://reinteractive.com/posts/199-developing-and-testing-rails-applications-with-subdomains)
[Capybara and Subdomains](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/acceptance-tests-with-subdomains)

Comment: Hello,   to get sub domains in nginx you do need to use a wild card in the config files. Here is a nice example of it in the second server block http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: Hey thanks for your help @JonWahl. It turns out I had my configuration correct, but the problem I had was IT related. They needed to generate a DNS entry.